# PHP Server. Should I download app content at startup

Tags: php, android, mysql, download

I am developing an app for android where I need some data from a mysql server. I have decided to use a php server to retrieve info from the database, and also to upload new data to the database, since android doesn't support MySql.

The app is some kind of a joke app where you have some opportunities regarding what kind of jokes you want.
You can get a completely random joke regardless of its categories. But you should also be able to get a list of jokes within a specific category.

My question goes here: Would it be the best to download all jokes from the database at the beginning of the app or would it be better to sort the jokes in the php server?

Comment: It depends. How much data is there to transfer? How long would that take? Could you do it in the background? How often should it be updated?

Comment: Why not cache some data locally so the application is quick to launch and respond, but only fetch small quantities of data at a time, maybe the top 10 for the day.

Comment: Well, this is my first app ever, and the first time i use databases, so i have no idea how much data is transfered

Comment: Then you should figure that out, it's quite an important design decision. :o)

Comment: I just thought about it, and if I use json it isn't that hard to filter the jokes. And then I could save a lot of time. Let's say i just nned to read like 10 jokes. Then it wouldn't be that efficient if i needed to download 10000 jokes everytime i start up the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up a system where you can download an index of jokes, then download them in bulk based on if they have already been downloaded or not. Just an Idea. For example, your code would go through its local database and send a request to the server to send back certain jokes.